# Azure Function CosmosDB function.json

Tags: azure-functions

I am new to Azure function but i have a question on how do i now apply below settings into my function class?

I am using **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB** library

function.json

```
{
  "type": "cosmosDB", 
  "name": "cosmosDb",
  "direction": "out",
  "connectionStringSetting": "COSMOS_CONNECTION_STRING",
  "databaseName": "%COSMOS_DATABASE%",
  "collectionName": "%COSMOS_COLLECTION%",
  "createIfNotExists": "true",
  "partitionKey": "/id"
}
```

Function.cs

```
public static async Task Run([CosmosDB()]IAsyncCollector<T> cosmosDb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sample binding data in the function.json file: Which is for direction "in". Similar lines you will have out with out again defining in Run param "cosmosDB".

```
{
"type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
"name": "documents",
"direction": "in",
"leaseCollectionName": "leases",
"connectionStringSetting": "<connection-app-setting>",
"databaseName": "Tasks",
"collectionName": "Items",
"createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true
```

}

Here's the C# script code:

```
   #r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client"

using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public static void Run(IReadOnlyList<Document> documents, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("Documents modified " + documents.Count);
    log.Info("First document Id " + documents[0].Id);
}
```

Same can be found in Microsoft documentation as well
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb.md

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-output?tabs=csharp

Similar way you can incorporate for direction type output.